# Upgrade CentOS 6.8 to 7.5

Tags: linux, centos

we have few virtual servers running CentOS 6.8. Yes, quite outdated. So we want to upgrade them to CentOS 7.5. I have looked around and it seems there is no straightforward official way how to do it. It is recommended to backup data and install new CentOS from scratch. This is the last resort for me because we have spent weeks configuring all services there. What I have found so far is that there is `redhat-upgrade-tool` but the comments range from "it works but you need to hack some RPMs" to "it will not work".

Is there any other way? Is there a straigthforward upgrade procedure?

Answer (score 2):

You can do [CentOS 6 to CentOS 7 Upgrade Using Red Hat Upgrade Tool](https://tekeye.uk/archive/vps/centos-6-to-centos-7-upgrade) for 64-bit.

I assume that the problem is that the VMs are 32-bit.

From the [Red Hat website](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/509373):

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 will only provide 64-bit ISO's, thus allowing only
>   a 64-bit operating environment. However, 32-bit is supported in the following
>   ways:
>
> - RHEL 7 will continue to provide selected libraries in both 32-bit and
>     64-bit, allowing 32-bit applications to run in the 64-bit RHEL 7 OS
>     environment. This functionality also exists for RHEL 5 & 6 as documented in
>     the knowledge article: [How to install 32-bit packages on a 64-bit
>     system](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/329913)
> - RHEL 7 will continue to support the multilib toolchain, allowing
>     applications to be compiled for both 32-bit and 64-bit.
> - RHEL 7 can host, using KVM virtualization technology, both 32-bit and
>     64-bit virtual guest instances of RHEL 5 and RHEL 6
>
> While RHEL 7 will not natively support 32-bit hardware, certified hardware
>   can be searched for in the [certified hardware database](https://hardware.redhat.com/).

I suggest that perhaps the best solution would be to recreate the VMs as 64-bit.
This will entail, as you have said, a backup of all data and installing
from scratch.

Comment: When I consider a backup procedure it makes sense that the backup machine will be new target machine.